# How to mock a user for unit testing a Spring Security based application?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

My application uses the Spring security configuration shown below, which requires a user to be authenticated. How can I mock a user for unit testing? It looks like I am being authenticated based on the content of `MockHttpServletRequest`; however, my test fails because I am denied access to the `/portfolio` endpoint and am instead redirected to the `/login` endpoint. I have followed the tutorial here: https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /portfolio
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@3ce7394f, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Location:"/login"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = /login
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Response header 'Location'
Expected: a string containing "/portfolio"
     but: was "/login"
Expected :a string containing "/portfolio"
Actual   :"/login"
<Click to see difference>


    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.HeaderResultMatchers.lambda$string$0(HeaderResultMatchers.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest.uploadPortfolioWithValidFile(PortfolioControllerTest.java:80)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform.run(JUnitPlatform.java:139)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)

16:35:57.243 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
16:35:57.277 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
16:35:57.400 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper]
16:35:57.433 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
16:35:57.446 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest]: class path resource [edu/bu/cs673/stockportfolio/unittests/api/PortfolioControllerTest-context.xml] does not exist
16:35:57.448 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest]: class path resource [edu/bu/cs673/stockportfolio/unittests/api/PortfolioControllerTestContext.groovy] does not exist
16:35:57.449 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
16:35:57.450 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest]: PortfolioControllerTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
16:35:57.714 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest]
16:35:57.818 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/mlewis/IntelliJProjects/CS673/StockPortfolio/target/classes/edu/bu/cs673/stockportfolio/StockportfolioApplication.class]
16:35:57.820 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.StockportfolioApplication for test class edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest
16:35:57.831 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.unittests.api.PortfolioControllerTest]: using defaults.
16:35:57.834 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener]
16:35:57.883 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@135606db, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@518caac3, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@68034211, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@4f74980d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6c372fe6, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@58594a11, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@2a3888c1, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@4167d97b, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@14fa86ae, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener@6e15fe2, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener@68f1b17f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@1722011b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@57ad2aa7, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@5b3f61ff, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@3e2059ae, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@398dada8, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@7cb502c]
16:35:57.892 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@31920ade testClass = PortfolioControllerTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1d483de4 testClass = PortfolioControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class edu.bu.cs673.stockportfolio.StockportfolioApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@4032d386 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@793f29ff, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@543295b0, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@fffa4b8f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@7a35b0f5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@645aa696, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@f44380e2, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@ef800a42, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@480d3575, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
16:35:58.033 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.0)

2021-07-31 16:35:59.499  INFO 12834 --- [           main] e.b.c.s.u.api.PortfolioControllerTest    : Starting PortfolioControllerTest using Java 13.0.1 on Michaels-MacBook-Air.local with PID 12834 (started by mlewis in /Users/mlewis/IntelliJProjects/CS673/StockPortfolio)
2021-07-31 16:35:59.504  INFO 12834 --- [           main] e.b.c.s.u.api.PortfolioControllerTest    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-07-31 16:35:59.582 DEBUG 12834 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@21ec5d87
2021-07-31 16:35:59.904  WARN 12834 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2021-07-31 16:36:02.405  INFO 12834 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@fb5aeed, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@626e0c86, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@51cab489, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@528c8c1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@491cafec, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@e91af20, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6b8d54da, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7cf63b9a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@73893ec1, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@15e1f8fe, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7418d76e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@14c99bf6]
2021-07-31 16:36:02.830 DEBUG 12834 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2021-07-31 16:36:02.963 DEBUG 12834 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 4 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2021-07-31 16:36:03.082 DEBUG 12834 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2021-07-31 16:36:03.109 DEBUG 12834 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2021-07-31 16:36:03.502  INFO 12834 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2021-07-31 16:36:03.503  INFO 12834 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2021-07-31 16:36:03.505  INFO 12834 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2021-07-31 16:36:03.580  INFO 12834 --- [           main] e.b.c.s.u.api.PortfolioControllerTest    : Started PortfolioControllerTest in 5.499 seconds (JVM running for 8.233)
```

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final HashService hashService;

    public AuthenticationService(UserRepository userRepository, HashService hashService) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.hashService = hashService;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        User user = userRepository.findAllByUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            String encodedSalt = user.getSalt();
            String hashedPassword = hashService.getHashedValue(password, encodedSalt);
            if (user.getPassword().equals(hashedPassword)) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, new ArrayList<>());
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class HashService {
    private final FluentLogger log = FluentLoggerFactory.getLogger(HashService.class);

    public String getHashedValue(String data, String salt) {
        byte[] hashedValue = null;

        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(data.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 5000, 128);

        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            hashedValue = factory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            log.error().log(e.getMessage());
        }

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((hashedValue));
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.authenticationService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/signup", "/css/*", "/js/*", "/images/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // -
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).invalidSessionUrl("/login");
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/portfolio")
public class PortfolioController {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final PortfolioService portfolioService;
    private final ValidationService validationService;
    private final ResponseService responseService;
    private final FluentLogger log = FluentLoggerFactory.getLogger(PortfolioController.class);

    public PortfolioController(UserService userService, PortfolioService portfolioService,
                               ValidationService validationService, ResponseService responseService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.portfolioService = portfolioService;
        this.validationService = validationService;
        this.responseService = responseService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String uploadPortfolio(Authentication authentication,
                                  @RequestParam("csvUpload")MultipartFile multipartFile, Model model) {
        // Removing implementation details for brevity 
}
```

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@WebMvcTest(PortfolioController.class)
public class PortfolioControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private MockMultipartFile mockFile;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockFile =
                new MockMultipartFile(
                        "portfolio",
                        "/Users/name/Downloads/TestPortfolio.csv",
                        "text/csv",
                        "portfolio".getBytes());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser()
    public void uploadPortfolioWithValidFile() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(
                multipart("/portfolio")
                        .file(mockFile))
                .andExpect(header().exists("Location"))
                .andExpect(header().string("Location", Matchers.containsString("/portfolio")))
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't mock data values. The reason for having the class `MockMultipartFile` is that it's an actual object (just with placeholder behavior). Start by eliminating the `@Mock`. You also failed to include your controller.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have edited my question to include the controller and have also removed the `@Mock` annotation on `MockMultipartFile`. I still run into issues though, so I am wondering if you have any thoughts on how to resolve the authentication part of the question?

Comment: Can you please include _the entire_ MockMvc output (it'll be about 30 lines long) as well as any security configuration you have applied?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- of course. Please see the edits I have included. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: I will note as a matter of custom (I don't know off the top of my head whether this changes the meaning) that it's unusual to restart multiple `http` "paragraphs"; rather, use `.and()` to "go back up one level". I _think_ your configuration should still work, but there are definitely DSLs where having multiple top-level instructions can produce interference.

Comment: I'm having a hard time telling why you're getting bounced. If updating your security config to the convention doesn't fix it, then set the log level for `org.springframework.web` to DEBUG and inspect the console trace for the request.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I added `org.springframework.web=DEBUG` and also added the stack trace. After going through it, I still can't tell why I am bounced.